# Magento 2 : Configuration array must have a key for 'dbname' that names the database instance

Tags: magento2.3

I have created below model for get navigation filter by category id but getting below error.

Working fine with fresh magento setup but not working with migration setup.

```
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Configuration array must have a key for 'dbname' that names the database instance
Exception #1 (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception): Configuration array must have a key for 'dbname' that names the database instance
```

**Code-**

```
namespace Nv\Finder\Model;

class FiltersManagement 
{
  protected $_filterableAttributeList;
  protected $_layerResolver;
  protected $_filterList;
  protected $_storeManagerInterface;
  protected $_response;
  protected $_redirFactory;

  public function __construct(
    \Magento\CatalogGraphQl\Model\Resolver\Layer\FilterableAttributesListFactory $filterableAttributeList,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterListFactory $filterList,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManagerInterface,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver
  )
  {
    $this->_filterList                      = $filterList;
    $this->_filterableAttributeList         = $filterableAttributeList;
    $this->_layerResolver                   = $layerResolver;
    $this->_storeManagerInterface           = $storeManagerInterface;
  }

  /**
    * GET  review by its ID
    *
    * @api
    * @return array
    * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
    *
    */
  public function getLayeredFilters()
  {
    $categoryId   = 147;
    $layer        = $this->_layerResolver->get();


    $layerType = "search";
    if ($categoryId){
      $layer->setCurrentCategory($categoryId);
      $layerType = "category";
    }

    $filterArray['store_id']  = $this->_storeManagerInterface->getStore()->getId();
    $filterableAttributesList = $this->_filterableAttributeList->create($layerType);

    $filterList = $this->_filterList->create(['filterableAttributes' => $filterableAttributesList]);
    $filters    = $filterList->getFilters($layer);
    $i = 0;
    foreach($filters as $filter)
    {
        // Don't show options with no items
      if (! $filter->getItemsCount()) {continue;}

      $availablefilter = (string)$filter->getName();
      $items           = $filter->getItems();
      $filterValues    = array();

      $j = 0;
      foreach($items as $item)
      {
        $filterValues[$j]['display'] = strip_tags($item->getLabel());
        $filterValues[$j]['value']   = $item->getValue();
        $filterValues[$j]['count']   = $item->getCount(); //Gives no. of products in each filter options
        $filterValues[$j]['url']     = $item->getUrl();   //Gives filter url.
        $j++;
      }

      if(!empty($filterValues) && count($filterValues)>1)
      {
        $filterArray['availablefilter'][$availablefilter] =  $filterValues;
      }
      $i++;

    }

    if (!isset($filterArray["availablefilter"])) {
      $filterArray['availablefilter'] = "No filters to show.";
    }

    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    $this->response = json_encode($filterArray);
    print_r($this->response,false);
    die();
  }

}
```